Is/was there a final university examination where the student was required to write down everything they knew about the subject (e.g. History)?
In about 1990, I heard that in Japan, after completing a History bachelor's degree course of several years duration, the student was required to write down everything they knew about History. It would take the student several days to write it all down, and to prevent cheating, the student had to stay in a sort of hotel room, and was supplied with food and drink by the examiners until he or she had finished.
Was there ever, in Japan, or anywhere else, a university examination like this?

Bad ideas abound.

The old Cambridge Mathematical Tripos was notoriously broad and difficult. It was divided into 2 parts each consisting of multiple exam papers to be completed over a few days.

That seems strange! nobody knows what he knows, unless they get into a situation that helps to know what they should remember. Mind is not like a computer with ordered/numbered cells of memory to check and recall the cells one by one.

I find it very unlikely considering I know people who graduated in Japan in the 90s. What is the source of information? It might be a confusion: History BSc theses are often just a very, very long (in the 90s typically hands-written) loosely organized braindumps. The particular person may have just referred his/her experience. Since libraries are generally packed, it is plausible that someone who is running out of time and has to write several hundred pages by hand just playing a hermit in a hotel room, but as an exam it is very unlikely.
